# Bash shell script to glob files in several directories, add to an archive and remove original file

Tags: bash

I am trying to write a bash script that does the following:

1. Enumerates through list of files in a directory, that match a specified pattern
2. Creates a tar file containing the matching files
3. Removes (i.e. deletes) the matched files from their source directories

To keep things simple, I intend to use a hard coded list of directories and file patterns

This is what I have come up with so far:

```
#!/bin/bash

filenames[0]='/home/user1/*.foo'
filenames[1]='/some/otherpath/*.fbar'

for f in ${filenames[@]}
   do
      echo "$f"
done
```

However, I am unusure on how to proceed from this point onward. Specifically, I need help on:

1. How to glob the files matching the pattern $f
2. How to add the ENTIRE list of matching files (i.e. from all directories) to a tar file in one go

Regarding deleting the files, I am thinking of simply iterating through the ENTIRE list obtained in step 2 above, and 'rm' the actual file - is there a better/quicker/more elegant way?

PS:

I am running this on Ubuntu 10.0.4 LTS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`tar(1)` supports an `--remove-files` option that will remove the files after adding them to the archive.

Depending upon what you're trying to do with your shell globs, you might be able to ignore doing all that extra work there, too. Try this:

```
tar cf /dir/archive.tar --remove-files /home/user1/*.foo /some/otherpath/*.fbar
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use a loop because you have many directories, you can use the `-r` option to append to the tar file. You can also use `--remove-files` to remove files after adding them to the archive.

```
filenames[0]='/home/user1/*.foo'
filenames[1]='/some/otherpath/*.fbar'

for f in "${filenames[@]}"
do
   tar -rvf --remove-files foo.tar $f
done
```

If you don't have the `--remove-files` option, use `rm $f` after the `tar` command.

Comment: I guess the archive gets created if it dosen't exist?. I am guessing this is the case, as I (obviously?), can't use the c option in a loop - as the file will get overwritten at each iteration ...

Comment: @oompahloompah yes it will created if it doesn't exist.